# Absolutely positioned div overflowing the boundary of relative parent

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a viewer bar that displays dots positioned `absolute` within a `relative` positioned parent of a specific size. The dots should appear a certain percentage from the left and top of the parent div. For some reason, when the dots are above a certain percentage, they overflow the parent. How can I keep the dots within the bounds of the parent div?

The parent div is nested within a bootstrap `.card`.

```css
.some-stuff {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="card">
  <div class="some-stuff">
    Here's some stuff that wont move
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="dot">
      &#x0307;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle showing my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/coopersamuel/ky7xzq1f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, this is fixed if you set the line-height property of .dot to 0 (or whatever the exact height of the dot is). I'm actually not clear on why (i removed my previous explanation bc it wasn't quite correct). If you insert any other text into the HTML where you have the special character, it aligns exactly how you'd expect. I suspect its an issue with that special character, it might display below the bottom line of text.

Comment: I actually edited my answer bc I don't think my initial explanation was right. With normal text it *should* place the bottom line of the text at the bottom line of the element. I think that special character is just weird!

Comment: Yeah it must be the special character, but i set the `line-height` property to 2px and it's working just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **CSS issue**.

If you assign the `child-element` the following classes.

```
position:absolute;
top:100%;
```

It will push your element exactly outside your container.

> You need to assign `position:relative;` to your container. Else it will take the absolute screen.

### Check this Error Fiddle:(It's below the screen)

I haven't assigned `position:relative` to outside container

```css
.relative {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.absolute {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Correct example.

```css
.relative {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.some-stuff {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="card">
  <div class="some-stuff">
    Here's some stuff that wont move
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="dot">
      &#x0307;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> You `top` should be less than `100%` and rest is trial and error to get it inside the parent div.

Comment: Looks like you may have your correct and incorrect examples flip flopped. Also, this doesn't quite solve the problem. I understand that I can keep the dot inside the boundary by keeping it under `100%`, but the dot placement is computed programmatically and might need to be at or near `100%`. I should've communicated better in my question.